# global name error in SimPy

Tags: python, numpy, simpy

I am trying to simulate points moving in 2D which have a probability of dying at every step. I am trying to learn SimPy and this is my first programming experience. Why do I get this error? and how to fix it? Thank you

```
from SimPy.SimulationTrace import *
import random as RD
import scipy as SP
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N=100
r1=0.02
r2=0.03
maxTime=100


class Point(Process):
    def __init__(self,coord,rate1,rate2):
          Process.__init__(self)
          self.x=coord[0]
          self.y=coord[1]
          self.rate1=r1
          self.rate2=r2

    def Move(self):
        RD.uniform(coord[0]-0.1,coord[0]+0.1)
        RD.uniform(coord[1]-0.1,coord[1]+0.1)
        yield hold,self,0.5
        self.x=coord[0]
        self.y=coord[1]
        yield hold,self,0.5

     #   reactivate(self,now())

    def die(self):
        if RD.random() < self.rate2:
          N-=1
          m.observe(N)
          yield cancel,self


initialize()
m=Monitor()
circular=[RD.uniform(0,100),RD.uniform(0,100)]
for object in xrange(N):
   object=Point(circular,r1,r2)   
activate(object,object.Move())
simulate(until=maxTime)
activate(object,object.die())
simulate(until=maxTime)

h=m.histogram(low=0.0,high=100,nbins=100)
g=m.yseries()
plt.plot(g)
plt.show()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\ask.py", line 46, in <module>
    simulate(until=maxTime)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SimPy\Globals.py", line 61, in simulate
    return sim.simulate(until = until)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SimPy\SimulationTrace.py", line 96, in simulate
    return Simulation.simulate(self, until)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SimPy\Simulation.py", line 581, in simulate
  step()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SimPy\Simulation.py", line 525, in step
  resultTuple = proc._nextpoint.next()
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\ask.py", line 23, in Move
    RD.uniform(coord[0]-0.3,coord[0]+0.3)
NameError: global name 'coord' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to replace

```
def Move(self):
```

with:

```
def Move(self, coord):
```

And after call this function passing the new coordinates as argument, something like:

```
obj.Move((10, 20))
```

Where in the example `(10, 20)` are the new object coordinates (I'm not sure that this is what your code does, but I guess it should be the natural behaviour of a function named 'Move').

From the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/executionmodel.html#index-8): *When a name is not found at all, a NameError exception is raised.*

Names in python (as explained better in [Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)) are what in other languages you call variables. So:

```
NameError: global name 'coord' is not defined
```

basically means that the compiler does not know what 'coord' is.

**Note:** You shouldn't call your variable 'object' shadowing the buil-in [`object`][3] that is the base class for every class.

Also I can't see the point in doing something like:

```
for i in xrange(N):   # Notice that I also used a different name here: i
    obj = Point(circular,r1,r2)
```

beacuse is the same as:

```
obj = Point(circular,r1,r2)
```

**Update:** Maybe what you're trying to do something like:

```
# maybe you want to put this inside a function so every time you get
# different random numbers
def circular():
     return RD.uniform(0,100), RD.uniform(0,100)

points = []
for i in xrange(N):
    p = Point(circular(), r1, r2)
    points.append(p)
    activate(p, p.Move(circular())

simulate(until=maxTime)

for p in points:
    activate(p, p.die())

simulate(until=maxTime)
```

**I never used SimPy so this is just my wild (and off-topic) guess.**

It also seems that you have `host` not defined in your `Move` method but maybe is imported with `from SimPy.SimulationTrace import *`. Using `from ... import *` is a bad practice because prevent others to know exactly what you're importing from that module (I presume that this was done in the SimPy tutorial for having a quick start, but you should import only what you need).

Comment: IMO, not only the definition, but the call to the Move function also needs to be modified here.

Comment: @AndreySobolev: Thanks, I made that explicit now.

Comment: @ Rik Poggi Thank you very much. Unfortunately, this doesn't fix my code. Yes I want the Move function to change the coordinates of each point in each step. I added "for i in xrange(N):" because I want the process to be executed over different 100 points not just one.

Comment: @Aya: You're welcome! :) I made an update to my answer, but if the problem stated in your question about the `global name 'coord' not defined` is solved you may consider accepting the answer that helped you the most (and up-vote the useful ones). Trying to solve other problems here will be *off-topic*. As explained in [What happens after I ask a question?](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-posts).

Comment: @Aya: I'd also say that you'll have more chance in correcting your code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) and/or making a specific new question about your new problem (supposing that the one about the 'coord' NameError is cleard).

Comment: @ Rik Poggi Thank you very much yes your answer solved the problem of global name, and it is very helpful. But then I get another problem. So I am trying fix it. And yes I think asking questions is very good for me to develop a working knowledge quickly for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Coord not defined in move function
You don't give it as argument, in my view